# How to translate paths with environment variables (Eg. %temp%)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am searching for a winapi function to expand paths with environment variables.
I have tried `GetFullPathName` but the result is weird: `"%appdata%\something"` becomes `"C:\<path to directory of exe>\%appdata%\something"`.

How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Cause I needed it with C#/.NET:
[Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

I hope it'll help somebody.